# Different result size between SELECT * and SELECT COUNT(*) on Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an strange behavior on an oracle database. We make a huge insert of around 3.1 million records. Everything fine so far.

Shortly after the insert  finished (around 1 too 10 minutes) I execute two statements.

1. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE
2. SELECT * FROM TABLE

The result from the first statement is fine it gives me the exact number of rows that was inserted.

The result from the second statement is now the problem. Depending on the time, the number of rows that are returned is for example around 500K lower than the result from the first statement. The difference of the two results is decreasing with time.

So I have to wait 15 to 30 minutes before both statements return the same number of rows.

I already talked with the oracle dba about this issue but he has no idea how this could happen.

Any ideas, questions or suggestions?

**Update**

When I select only an index column I get the correct row count.
When I instead select an non index column I get again the wrong row count.

Comment: Are you running both selects in the same session? How are you inserting the rows? Is this reproducible (that is, it happens *every time* you insert into the table?How do you know how many rows are returned by `select * from TABLE` ? Do you scroll through them in a client or IDE? What is the behaviour of `select count(*) from (select * from TABLE)`?

Comment: No the both select statements uses different sessions. What do you mean with how do I insert? We use an normal INSERT Statement LIKE INSERT INTO TABLE (COLUM1, COLUMN2...COLUMNX) VALUES (1, 2, ...X) . Yes it can be reproduced and happens also during other inserts. We have an count option in our software that can simply count all rows that are returned. I will test your statement.

Comment: The result from the statement SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE) give me the correct row count.

Comment: Yes, but in the same time window when `select * from TABLE` gives you the wrong row count?

Comment: @APC Yes this is correct. I executed
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE)
and this gave me the correct row count. After this i directly executet only the statement
    SELECT * FROM TABLE
and i got the wrong row count.

Comment: In the same session? Hmmm. This is pretty weird, but Oracle almost never does weirdness like this: there must be some peculiarity in the table, the environment or the loading process. Alas it's pretty difficult to diagnose this sort of thing remotely.

Comment: Shot in the dark. Does the table contain out-of-line storage columns? Such as CLOB or BLOB, or nested tables?

Comment: Execution plans might help. We expect `select count(*) from TABLE` to read the primary key index and `select * from TABLE` to execute a Full Table Scan. But if that's not the case then that would be a clue.

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind after having read this : _We have an count option in our software that can simply count all rows that are returned_  is **Are you sure that your software is counting the rows correctly on such large results ?**

Comment: @APC: No we don´t have CLOBs BLOBs or nested table. I will try to get an execution plan. Another hint i found out. When I select only one column the row count is correct.
So SELECT * FROM TABLE gives me the wrong row count
But SELECT Column1 FROM TABLE gives me the correct row-count

Comment: @Thomas G yes i can ensure you that the counting is function correctly. This was one of the first things we checked. We make additonal statements on top of the insert and we get errors due to missing rows.

Comment: Then, have you tried to output all rows returned by the `SELECT *` in a file to spot the missing records? Are the missings random or the last records inserted in the table? That won't answer the question but eliminate some possibilities. A dichotomy is the only approach here :)

Comment: How exactly are you counting the rows from the `SELECT * FROM TABLE` What programming are you using? Can you show us the code that does it? Is it possible the "driver layer" somehow limits the number of rows returned from a query?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I dont have direct insight how the software I am using is counting the rows. Also I can´t simply grab the code. But we checked the row count also with sql plus so we have two different programs that show the problem. We use an JDBC driver. Since the driver worked flawless in other projects with a lot more data volumne this should be not the problem.

Comment: @ThomasG I will try this out but this will take a while.

Comment: I wonder if this is a corrupt index issue. If there's a primary key on the table, then maybe its corresponding index is being used in the `select count(*) from ...` query, but if it's corrupt somehow then all bets are off as to whether the count will be correct. If I were you, I would try rebuilding the indexes and then check the results of the `select * from ...` and `select count(*) from ...` queries. It's rare that an index is corrupt to the point where it returns the wrong information when queried, but I have come across the situation once or twice before.

Comment: @Boneist I don´t think this is an Index issue. The table I insert the data into is newly created before the insert. Actually for me it looks like it is some sort of caching on the oracle side. It seems to me that Oracle only write the Primary Key Columns directly so it can check if the PK is violated or not. All non PK columns are then written with an delay.

Comment: That's not how Oracle works. We'd all be seeing weird inconsistent results if that were the case! It's true that data may not necessarily be written straight away to the data blocks (e.g. Delayed Block Cleanout) but the data is immediately available to be viewed. Something else is going on here, but what that is I don't know. Please update your question to include the explain plans of both queries.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't sounds like a bug to me, if I understood you correctly, it just takes time for Oracle to fetch the entire table . After all, 3 Mil is not a small amount.

As opposed to count, which brings 1 record with the total number of rows.

If after some waiting, the number of records being output equals to the number that the count query returns, then everything is fine.

Comment: It is true the first statement only returns one row meanwhile the other statement hast to return all 3 million rows. But anyway when both statements are finished they should have the same result. I mean the number that is returned from the first statement has to be the same number as the rowcount from the second statement. And that is not the case.

Comment: You said after 15 - 30 minutes it works fine. What does that mean? Are you running both in the same session?

Comment: When I execute the statements mentioned above after an waiting time of around 15 up too 30 minutes the results are as expected. That is what i mean with after 15 - 30 minutes everything works fine. And no the both statements uses differnt sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already verified with these things:

1- Count single column instead of * ALL to verify both result

2- You can verify both queries result by adding where clause and gradually select more rows by removing conditions so that you can get the issue where it is returning different value from both.

Comment: 1 COUNT of single column instead of * don´t make an difference.

Comment: Can you please also try by selecting partial count from both queries by using some conditions.

Comment: 2 What is the idea behind this? I mean how could this help me to understand what happend?

Comment: In this way we can find In which depth of data its giving different count or only in case of counting WHOLE data.

Comment: One should point out that a count on a single column won't count rows which are NULL

Answer (score -1):

I think you should check Execution plan to identify missing indexes to improve performance. 
Add missing Indexes and check the result.

**Why missing Indexes are impotent:**

To count row, Oracle engine no need to go throw paging operation. But while fetching all the details from a table, it requires to go through paging.

And paging process depends on indexes created on a table to fetch the data effectively and fast.

So to decrease time for your second statement, you should find missing indexes and create those indexes.

**How to Find Missing Indexes:**

You can start with DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY, and look at all statements that contain that type of hint.

From there, you can pull the index name coming from that hint, and then do a lookup on dba_indexes to see if the index exists, is valid, etc.

Comment: I am not quite sure how the execution plan can help me? I don´t have performance problems. Also how could a missing index be responsible for this?

Comment: Updated details in answer.

Comment: This is an answer to a different question.